# Dockerfile: unable to copy file

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

As my Docker container starts up, I need to run this line:

```
cp /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Both of these files only exist in the Docker container after some packages have been installed.

In the Dockerfile, I have tried:

```
RUN cp /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

```
COPY /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

```
ENTRYPOINT ["cp","/lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"]
```

And also created a bash script that contains (among other things) this line. I know the script has run as the other changes it makes are present, but the file is not copied.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

apk add build-base
apk add libc6-compat

cp /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Then run with

```
RUN ./my_bash_script.sh
```

However, when I use the command line in the Docker container, and run the line manually, it works.

Why are the Dockerfile commands not copying this file?

Edit: My complete Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:alpine
ENV APP_NAME hello-world
ADD env_setup.sh .
RUN chmod +x env_setup.sh
RUN ./env_setup.sh
WORKDIR /home/helloworld
ADD vendor/ ./vendor/
COPY main.go .
COPY go.mod .
```

Comment: Why do you think the file is not being copied, particularly with the first example? Is the source of the file being copied in your image or on the host performing the build?

Comment: @BMitch It's not a matter of opinion, the file is literally not where it should be copied to (in the final build, at least)

Comment: "Why do you think" didn't mean to imply your opinion. I'm asking for the commands being run and output seen that show how you are verifying this. Often people are getting useful error messages they don't include in the question, or they are looking in the wrong place, but we don't know without seeing what you're looking at. See [mcve] for more details.

Comment: @BMitch when running `ls /lib/` the desired file was not present. Moreover, my code requiring this library still would not run as it could also not find this library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple  resources may be specified but the paths of files and directories will be interpreted as relative to the source of the context of the build

Try to firstly copy the file to the local directory where the Dockerfile is located

Then

```
COPY libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Comment: By "fetch the file" - find the required file and copy it to my local computer for instance?

Comment: Yes, copy it to the local directory where the Dockerfile is located. I will update the answer